# Mysql how to get all rows from a table that the a field not having the particular value..?

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have a table which contains `student_id`, `course_id` and `result`. The table structure is as follows

[image]

I need to get `course_id` which the result is 0 and another condition is that the result may not be 1 for that course.

In that image the `course_id` 633 has both `result` 0 and 1. so that the particular `course_id` Do not get from that table.

Regards,
John

Comment: whats your point here then? Whats your requirement?

Comment: what exactly is ur req? Is this d condition ur lookin for "select course_id from table_name where result=0 and result!=1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT student_id,course_id,SUM(CASE WHEN result=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 0Count
FROM TableName
GROUP BY student_id,course_id
HAVING 0Count=0
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/531213/5)

**Explanation:**

Query will returns students with `result=0` and who do not have a `result=1` for that course.

**Sample Output:**

```
student_id   course_id   result
3061         663         0
3061         663         1
3062         664         1
3063         665         0
```

The result will be:

```
STUDENT_ID   COURSE_ID       0COUNT
-----------------------------------
3063         664             0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT course_id FROM table_name WHERE result <> 1
```

edit: unused selections where kicked

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see. I think you are looking for this code

```
SELECT course_id FROM table_name WHERE result = 0 AND result NOT LIKE "%1%";
```

Let me know how is it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.course_id
 FROM table_name t1
 WHERE t1.result = 0
   AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM table_name t2
     WHERE t2.course_id = t1.course_id
     AND t2.result = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE course_id NOT IN
    (SELECT course_id
     FROM TABLE_NAME
     WHERE RESULT=0
       AND course_id IN
         (SELECT course_id
          FROM TABLE_NAME
          WHERE RESULT=1))
```